# Dependent combo box with multiple select

Tags: javascript, combobox, multiple-select

I've downloaded and tried a code of dependent combo box. This is HTML & Javascript. It's running well. But my problem is, when i want to select **more than one option/value**, in the depended combo box, i don't know how to do that.

For example if i want to select Canada for the country, and select Toronto & Montreal for the cities.

I know that we have to change the field name of the 2nd combo box to be an array, so i can capture all selected option in my PHP. From name="cities" to **name="cities[]"**. But i doesn't work here. Please help me to solve this problem, how to do that. So i can select the option more than one value.

Here is the code

```
<form name="classic">
    <select name="countries" size="4" onChange="updatecities(this.selectedIndex)" style="width: 150px">
        <option selected>Select A City</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>

    <select name="cities" size="4" style="width: 150px" onClick="alert(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value)" >
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var countrieslist=document.classic.countries
    var citieslist=document.classic.cities

    var cities=new Array()
    cities[0]=""
    cities[1]=["New York|newyorkvalue", "Los Angeles|loangelesvalue", "Chicago|chicagovalue", "Houston|houstonvalue", "Austin|austinvalue"]
    cities[2]=["Vancouver|vancouvervalue", "Tonronto|torontovalue", "Montreal|montrealvalue", "Calgary|calgaryvalue"]
    cities[3]=["London|londonvalue", "Glasgow|glasgowsvalue", "Manchester|manchestervalue", "Edinburgh|edinburghvalue", "Birmingham|birminghamvalue"]

    function updatecities(selectedcitygroup){
        citieslist.options.length=0
        if (selectedcitygroup>0){
            for (i=0; i<cities[selectedcitygroup].length; i++)
                citieslist.options[citieslist.options.length]=new Option(cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[0], cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[1])
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Best Regards, SJAinun

Comment: Also: `<select multiple>` in order to be able to select more than one option at a time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that is right. But the Javascript is not working when i change the field name as name="cities[]". I think the exactly problem is here. Because it has to be an array. Do you know any other way to do that?

Comment: Because adding <select multiple> attribute only is not enough, we have to change the field name as an array, so that all sent values can be captured in the PHP. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

On the subject selecting multiple values in a select list and providing an array upon submission to a PHP script, adding the "multiple" attribute and appending the PHP array push shorthand "[]" to the input name value (in this case `name=cities[]`) accomplishes that.

In this case, changing the name of the "cities" select list causes the `var citieslist=document.classic.cities` to fail since it no longer exists. To fix that one can add an `id="cities"` attribute to the select list or use square bracket notation with a string key: `var citieslist=document.classic['cities[]']`.

Also, in the code provided, the for loop was missing the opening curly bracket.

```
<form name="classic">
    <select name="countries" size="4" onChange="updatecities(this.selectedIndex)" style="width: 150px">
        <option selected>Select A City</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple name="cities[]" size="4" style="width: 150px">
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var countrieslist=document.classic.countries;
    var citieslist=document.classic['cities[]'];

    var cities=new Array()
    cities[0]=""
    cities[1]=["New York|newyorkvalue", "Los Angeles|loangelesvalue", "Chicago|chicagovalue", "Houston|houstonvalue", "Austin|austinvalue"]
    cities[2]=["Vancouver|vancouvervalue", "Tonronto|torontovalue", "Montreal|montrealvalue", "Calgary|calgaryvalue"]
    cities[3]=["London|londonvalue", "Glasgow|glasgowsvalue", "Manchester|manchestervalue", "Edinburgh|edinburghvalue", "Birmingham|birminghamvalue"]

    function updatecities(selectedcitygroup){
        citieslist.options.length=0
        if (selectedcitygroup>0){
            for (i=0; i<cities[selectedcitygroup].length; i++) {
                citieslist.options[citieslist.options.length]=new Option(cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[0], cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[1])
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much... it's running :)